# How to check when sequence repeats in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am generating a sequence by [combining musical rhythms](https://link.band).

[image]

Basically, the green is the sound, and the purple is the absence of sound. It moves around the wheel. At each point in the wheel I draw a number (or letter) symbolizing the position of the rotation of the wheel.

Given that I am constructing an array at each step of the beat (where each item in the array is 3 digits), how do I tell once the combination/rhythm fully repeats *in the combination of these beats*?

That is to say, I want to find when the combination of 3 and 4 (beats 1 and 2 in the visual) repeat, and when 3 and 5 repeat, 4 and 5 repeat, and 3, 4, and 5 together all repeat.

I would like to stop the array from growing once the beat repeats.

Perhaps we can precompute everything so we know when it repeats, but even then, how can it be accomplished, given that we don't necessarily know mentally when it repeats?

I would like to extend this to arbitrary "beats" and alphabets. And doing it differently so that say for example purple = 0 and green = 1, and we draw 101, 111, etc.

I guess there's two questions there. So the first question for this post is, how do I tell when a sequence like the above (rendering the index of each) repeats? Without using fancy math such as telling what the common factor is of these and going from there. As that won't work for other sequences. Basically I just want to know when you can tell the overall "final" sequence repeats.

Here is an example of the code copied/modified to demonstrate how to generate sequences. You can go from there in removing the string output or using the generated data as input for some algorithm.

```js
const alphabet = `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.split('')

const baseDrum = {
  rhythm: [1, 0, 0],
  position: 2,
}

const hiHat = {
  rhythm: [1, 2, 2, 2],
  position: 3,
}

const flute = {
  rhythm: [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  position: 4,
}

const instruments = [flute, baseDrum, hiHat]

const update = () => {
  instruments.forEach(instrument => {
    if (instrument.position == instrument.rhythm.length - 1) {
      instrument.position = 0
    } else {
      instrument.position++
    }
  })
}

const sequence1 = []
const sequence2 = []
const sequence3 = []
const sequence4 = []
const sequence5 = []

function generate() {
  const numbers = [
    baseDrum.position + 1,
    hiHat.position + 1,
    flute.position + 1,
  ]

  const playNumbers = [
    baseDrum.rhythm[baseDrum.position],
    hiHat.rhythm[hiHat.position] - 1,
    flute.rhythm[flute.position],
  ]

  const lettersString = numbers.map(x => alphabet[x]).join('')
  const numbersString = numbers.join('')

  const playNumbersDigit = parseInt(playNumbers.join(''), 2)
  const playLettersString = alphabet[playNumbersDigit]
  const playNumbersString = playNumbers.join('')

  sequence1.push(lettersString)
  sequence2.push(numbersString)
  sequence3.push(playNumbersDigit)
  sequence4.push(playLettersString)
  sequence5.push(playNumbersString)
}

let i = 0

while (i++ < 100) {
  update()
  generate()
}

console.log(JSON.stringify({ sequence1, sequence2, sequence3, sequence4, sequence5 }, null, 2))
```

Comment: We need to see the data representation of the colored dots to show how to identify pattern in data object/arrays/constructs. In other words, please paste the code that goes with this

Comment: I guess you'd need to start by defining what is the minimum pattern for a repeating set - 2 consecutive values, 3, 40?

Comment: @Kinglish I have added a generator to generate some output based on how the app works.

Comment: So, do you want to find out when any of the objects in the array repeat (meaning every property in the object is duplicate)?

Comment: Not quite, just when the string sequences repeat. I've modified the code to make it clearer the sequences. So there are 5 different sequences. I would like to see when any one of those sequences repeats. The general algorithm should work for any generated sequence of strings.

Comment: Is the answer I provided what you were looking for? It finds the first repeating object in the array and takes everything that preceeded it as the 'pattern' -- let me know

Comment: I was looking for something a bit more efficient and for individual strings.

Comment: Got it. I added an alternate to my answer. No loops, no comparisons, just a one line raw substring find. Definitely more efficient. Let me know if that's more your speed.

Comment: To find how many steps until repeat, multiply the length of the individual cycles. To get the smallest combined cycle size, find the Greatest Common Divisor (GCD), divide all cycle lengths by that and then multiply the results together. From that, you know the max size of the array and then just need to fill it up. In your example, for all three loops combined, the GCD is 1 and the minimum cycle size is 60.

Answer (score -1):

A barebones string finder is one option:

```
let out = JSON.stringify(output),
output = JSON.parse(out
          .substr(0, out
            .indexOf(
              JSON.stringify(output[0]),2
            )-1) + "]"
         );
```

which folds into a zippy little one-liner:

```
output = JSON.parse(out.substr(0,out.indexOf(JSON.stringify(output[0]),2)-1)+"]") ;
```

A less efficient loop version is included as an alternate. We just loop through each item, turn it into a string, test to see if we've encountered it before and if not store it. Once we find the repeat, we stop.

```js
const output = [{
    "lettersString": "bbb",
    "numbersString": "111",
    "playNumbersDigit": 5,
    "playLettersString": "f",
    "playNumbersString": "101"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ccc",
    "numbersString": "222",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ddd",
    "numbersString": "333",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bee",
    "numbersString": "144",
    "playNumbersDigit": 6,
    "playLettersString": "g",
    "playNumbersString": "110"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cbf",
    "numbersString": "215",
    "playNumbersDigit": 0,
    "playLettersString": "a",
    "playNumbersString": "000"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dcb",
    "numbersString": "321",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bdc",
    "numbersString": "132",
    "playNumbersDigit": 6,
    "playLettersString": "g",
    "playNumbersString": "110"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ced",
    "numbersString": "243",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dbe",
    "numbersString": "314",
    "playNumbersDigit": 0,
    "playLettersString": "a",
    "playNumbersString": "000"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bcf",
    "numbersString": "125",
    "playNumbersDigit": 6,
    "playLettersString": "g",
    "playNumbersString": "110"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cdb",
    "numbersString": "231",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dec",
    "numbersString": "342",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bbd",
    "numbersString": "113",
    "playNumbersDigit": 5,
    "playLettersString": "f",
    "playNumbersString": "101"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cce",
    "numbersString": "224",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ddf",
    "numbersString": "335",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "beb",
    "numbersString": "141",
    "playNumbersDigit": 7,
    "playLettersString": "h",
    "playNumbersString": "111"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cbc",
    "numbersString": "212",
    "playNumbersDigit": 0,
    "playLettersString": "a",
    "playNumbersString": "000"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dcd",
    "numbersString": "323",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bde",
    "numbersString": "134",
    "playNumbersDigit": 6,
    "playLettersString": "g",
    "playNumbersString": "110"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cef",
    "numbersString": "245",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dbb",
    "numbersString": "311",
    "playNumbersDigit": 1,
    "playLettersString": "b",
    "playNumbersString": "001"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bcc",
    "numbersString": "122",
    "playNumbersDigit": 6,
    "playLettersString": "g",
    "playNumbersString": "110"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cdd",
    "numbersString": "233",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dee",
    "numbersString": "344",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bbf",
    "numbersString": "115",
    "playNumbersDigit": 4,
    "playLettersString": "e",
    "playNumbersString": "100"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ccb",
    "numbersString": "221",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ddc",
    "numbersString": "332",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bed",
    "numbersString": "143",
    "playNumbersDigit": 7,
    "playLettersString": "h",
    "playNumbersString": "111"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cbe",
    "numbersString": "214",
    "playNumbersDigit": 0,
    "playLettersString": "a",
    "playNumbersString": "000"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dcf",
    "numbersString": "325",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bdb",
    "numbersString": "131",
    "playNumbersDigit": 7,
    "playLettersString": "h",
    "playNumbersString": "111"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cec",
    "numbersString": "242",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dbd",
    "numbersString": "313",
    "playNumbersDigit": 1,
    "playLettersString": "b",
    "playNumbersString": "001"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bce",
    "numbersString": "124",
    "playNumbersDigit": 6,
    "playLettersString": "g",
    "playNumbersString": "110"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cdf",
    "numbersString": "235",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "deb",
    "numbersString": "341",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bbc",
    "numbersString": "112",
    "playNumbersDigit": 4,
    "playLettersString": "e",
    "playNumbersString": "100"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ccd",
    "numbersString": "223",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dde",
    "numbersString": "334",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bef",
    "numbersString": "145",
    "playNumbersDigit": 6,
    "playLettersString": "g",
    "playNumbersString": "110"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cbb",
    "numbersString": "211",
    "playNumbersDigit": 1,
    "playLettersString": "b",
    "playNumbersString": "001"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dcc",
    "numbersString": "322",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bdd",
    "numbersString": "133",
    "playNumbersDigit": 7,
    "playLettersString": "h",
    "playNumbersString": "111"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cee",
    "numbersString": "244",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dbf",
    "numbersString": "315",
    "playNumbersDigit": 0,
    "playLettersString": "a",
    "playNumbersString": "000"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bcb",
    "numbersString": "121",
    "playNumbersDigit": 7,
    "playLettersString": "h",
    "playNumbersString": "111"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cdc",
    "numbersString": "232",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ded",
    "numbersString": "343",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bbe",
    "numbersString": "114",
    "playNumbersDigit": 4,
    "playLettersString": "e",
    "playNumbersString": "100"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ccf",
    "numbersString": "225",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ddb",
    "numbersString": "331",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bec",
    "numbersString": "142",
    "playNumbersDigit": 6,
    "playLettersString": "g",
    "playNumbersString": "110"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cbd",
    "numbersString": "213",
    "playNumbersDigit": 1,
    "playLettersString": "b",
    "playNumbersString": "001"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dce",
    "numbersString": "324",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bdf",
    "numbersString": "135",
    "playNumbersDigit": 6,
    "playLettersString": "g",
    "playNumbersString": "110"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ceb",
    "numbersString": "241",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dbc",
    "numbersString": "312",
    "playNumbersDigit": 0,
    "playLettersString": "a",
    "playNumbersString": "000"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bcd",
    "numbersString": "123",
    "playNumbersDigit": 7,
    "playLettersString": "h",
    "playNumbersString": "111"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cde",
    "numbersString": "234",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "def",
    "numbersString": "345",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bbb",
    "numbersString": "111",
    "playNumbersDigit": 5,
    "playLettersString": "f",
    "playNumbersString": "101"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ccc",
    "numbersString": "222",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ddd",
    "numbersString": "333",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bee",
    "numbersString": "144",
    "playNumbersDigit": 6,
    "playLettersString": "g",
    "playNumbersString": "110"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cbf",
    "numbersString": "215",
    "playNumbersDigit": 0,
    "playLettersString": "a",
    "playNumbersString": "000"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dcb",
    "numbersString": "321",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bdc",
    "numbersString": "132",
    "playNumbersDigit": 6,
    "playLettersString": "g",
    "playNumbersString": "110"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ced",
    "numbersString": "243",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dbe",
    "numbersString": "314",
    "playNumbersDigit": 0,
    "playLettersString": "a",
    "playNumbersString": "000"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bcf",
    "numbersString": "125",
    "playNumbersDigit": 6,
    "playLettersString": "g",
    "playNumbersString": "110"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cdb",
    "numbersString": "231",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dec",
    "numbersString": "342",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bbd",
    "numbersString": "113",
    "playNumbersDigit": 5,
    "playLettersString": "f",
    "playNumbersString": "101"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cce",
    "numbersString": "224",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ddf",
    "numbersString": "335",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "beb",
    "numbersString": "141",
    "playNumbersDigit": 7,
    "playLettersString": "h",
    "playNumbersString": "111"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cbc",
    "numbersString": "212",
    "playNumbersDigit": 0,
    "playLettersString": "a",
    "playNumbersString": "000"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dcd",
    "numbersString": "323",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bde",
    "numbersString": "134",
    "playNumbersDigit": 6,
    "playLettersString": "g",
    "playNumbersString": "110"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cef",
    "numbersString": "245",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dbb",
    "numbersString": "311",
    "playNumbersDigit": 1,
    "playLettersString": "b",
    "playNumbersString": "001"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bcc",
    "numbersString": "122",
    "playNumbersDigit": 6,
    "playLettersString": "g",
    "playNumbersString": "110"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cdd",
    "numbersString": "233",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dee",
    "numbersString": "344",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bbf",
    "numbersString": "115",
    "playNumbersDigit": 4,
    "playLettersString": "e",
    "playNumbersString": "100"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ccb",
    "numbersString": "221",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ddc",
    "numbersString": "332",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bed",
    "numbersString": "143",
    "playNumbersDigit": 7,
    "playLettersString": "h",
    "playNumbersString": "111"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cbe",
    "numbersString": "214",
    "playNumbersDigit": 0,
    "playLettersString": "a",
    "playNumbersString": "000"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dcf",
    "numbersString": "325",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bdb",
    "numbersString": "131",
    "playNumbersDigit": 7,
    "playLettersString": "h",
    "playNumbersString": "111"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cec",
    "numbersString": "242",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dbd",
    "numbersString": "313",
    "playNumbersDigit": 1,
    "playLettersString": "b",
    "playNumbersString": "001"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bce",
    "numbersString": "124",
    "playNumbersDigit": 6,
    "playLettersString": "g",
    "playNumbersString": "110"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "cdf",
    "numbersString": "235",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "deb",
    "numbersString": "341",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bbc",
    "numbersString": "112",
    "playNumbersDigit": 4,
    "playLettersString": "e",
    "playNumbersString": "100"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "ccd",
    "numbersString": "223",
    "playNumbersDigit": 3,
    "playLettersString": "d",
    "playNumbersString": "011"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "dde",
    "numbersString": "334",
    "playNumbersDigit": 2,
    "playLettersString": "c",
    "playNumbersString": "010"
  },
  {
    "lettersString": "bef",
    "numbersString": "145",
    "playNumbersDigit": 6,
    "playLettersString": "g",
    "playNumbersString": "110"
  }
]

// here's a raw string method
let out = JSON.stringify(output),
  soutput = JSON.parse(out.substr(0, out.indexOf(JSON.stringify(output[0]), 2) - 1) + "]");
console.log(soutput.length, soutput);

// here's a loop method

let ctr = 0,
  rep = false;
let pattern = output.map(o => JSON.stringify(o)).reduce((b, a, i) => {
  if (!rep && b.includes(a)) {
    rep = true;
    ctr = i;
  } else if (!rep) b.push(a)
  return b
}, []).map(o => JSON.parse(o));

console.log('output length', output.length, '/pattern length:', pattern.length, '/pattern:', pattern)
```